# Android autocomplete get position of selected item in whole list

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Yes,I know there is position parametar in `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` callback, but this parametar return position of filtered(shown) list.
For example I have `_countriesEvisitor` arraylist and I would like to get selected country object by looking into position like this:

```
 public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener setOnCitizenshipAutocompleteItemClickListener(){


    return (adapterView, view, position, id) -> {
        CountryEvisitor citizenship=new CountryEvisitor();

        citizenship=_countriesEvisitor.get(position);
        _visit.setCitizenship(citizenship);
    };
}
```

`_countriesEvisitor` has 250 items, and when I start typing for example `Hrvatska` I get only one item, and it has position 0 (because it is first and only one in shown list) although it is 247th in the `_countriesEvisitor` list from which list autocomplete adapter is made of.

How to get selected country?

Comment: get position from filtered list

Answer (score -1):

Just use like below code.

```
  public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener setOnCitizenshipAutocompleteItemClickListener(){
  return (adapterView, view, position, id) -> {

    CountryEvisitor citizenship= (CountryEvisitor ) view.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    citizenship=_citizenship.getcitizenship();
    _visit.setCitizenship(citizenship);

  };}
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers, explain to the OP what the difference is. Your code does not work because you do this first `CountryEvisitor citizenship= (CountryEvisitor ) view.getAdapter().getItem(position);` and then you use `.get()` on the same object and... assign it again?

Comment: I updated my answer.access data member  using citizenship object.

Answer (score -2):

Keep a second list with the original items, and search through the list matching your search result and get the index of that item

```
...
_countriesEvisitor.get(position);
int result = -1;
for(int x = 0; x < originalList.size; x++) {
    if (/* some check here */) {
        result = x;
        break;
    }
}
if (result != -1) {
    // check if result is not -1 and use the index
}
```

Comment: You dont understand question I think

Comment: Yes I do. You filter the results you get for example 10 results from the 100. And when you press the second item, it is not the second index of the original 100 items. So keep a copy of the original items and loop through them to find the index.

Comment: Sorry, your don't have to downvote only because I downvoted your answer. If  you think that question is unclear you can tell me.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer as seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/et5j57f.png). And if two people did not understand your question, I think it's wrong at your end and you did not explain it well enough.

Comment: @Vlado so explain it better what you're trying to achieve and don't just say that people are downvoting you when they aren't

Comment: @Vlado Or don't explain it better.